# vs code go to definition not working React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I simply can not use go to definition in VS code.

I am trying to click on Component name and jump in file.

Ctrl + Click or F12 Must work as defined in VS Code documentation.

Using React Native, React.

was trying to figure out all day, searched through settings and web but no solution ...
should I reset VS code Settings in this case ?

[image: Code]